# Why does IPython notebook only output one DIV from this code?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In an IPython notebook I input this code in a cell:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML("""<div>One</div>""")
HTML("""<div>Two</div>""")
```

How come the output cell only contains the second div?

EDIT. @Dunno has shown how I can put all the html into one `HTML()` and both elements are rendered, but I still don't understand what's going on. Here's a more general case:

When I enter this in an input cell:

```
1
2
3
```

The output is

```
3
```

But if I enter the following:

```
print 1
print 2
print 3
```

Then I get this output:

```
1
2
3
```

What's the difference? Is IPython notebook only evaluating the last statement when I don't use `print` statements? Or is each subsequent evaluation overwriting the previous one?

Comment: I think you have to use one call to the `HTML` function (i.e. `HTML("""<div>One</div><div>Two</div>""")`, but I might be wrong

Comment: I edited my answer below to address your follow up question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah I found some [documentation](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/notebooks/Part%205%20-%20Rich%20Display%20System.ipynb#HTML) on this, and `HTML` is actually a class, not a function.

So the correct code would be

```
from IPython.display import HTML
myhtml = HTML("""<div>One</div><div>Two</div>""") #make the html object
myhtml #display it
```

Now it makes sense why your code displays only one div.

To display multiple parts create multiple variables, containing the html and then concatenate them inside one call to HTML.

```
div1 = """<div>One</div>"""
div2 = """<div>Two</div>"""
myhtml = HTML(div1 + div2)
myhtml
```

---

**Edit:**

[I opened a ticket](http://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5208) on ipython's github profile to see if it's a bug or a feature that only the last line of statements is displayed. Turns out, it's planned behaviour:

*quoting Thomas Kluyver:*

> This is deliberate, because if you call something in a for loop that returns a value:
>
> ```
> for line in lines:
>     f.write(line)  # Returns number of bytes written
> ```
>
> You probably don't want to see all those numbers in the output.
>
> The rule in IPython is: if the last statement in your code is an expression, we display its >value. 1;2 is a pair of statements, whereas 1,2 is one statement, so both values will >display.
>
> I hope that explains things a bit. We're happy to revisit decisions like this, but it's >been this way for years, and I don't think anyone has taken issue with it.

Comment: Great work @Dunno - thanks for seeking out the answer. And Thomas gave a very good example to explain the behaviour which makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 2):

Just a small addition to @Dunno's answer: if you want to display multiple `IPython.display.DisplayObject` objects (this includes `HTML` objects but also images etc.) from a single cell, you can use the `IPython.display.display` function.

For example, you can do:

```
from IPython.display import HTML, Image, display
display(HTML("""<div>One</div>"""))
display(HTML("""<div>Two</div>"""))
display(Image("http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a", format="png"))
```

[image: Output of the above code]